# How to get and compare libcurl version?

Tags: c, version, libcurl

I am using libcurl setting OAuth 2.0 access token. Since libcurl 7.33 `CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, char *token);` option was added. Now I need to get the libcurl version and compare it with 7.33. In case where version is 7.33 or higher I will use CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER otherwise I will do something else. 
I know I should somehow use `curl_version_info_data *curl_version_info( CURLversion type );` but I have no idea, how the data in struct look like and how to compare them to 7.33 version. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to detect version at run-time, you can use [curl_version_info](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_version_info.html)() in a style like this:

```
curl_version_info_data *d = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);

/* compare with the 24 bit hex number in 8 bit fields */
if(d->version_num >= 0x072100) {
  /* this is libcurl 7.33.0 or later */
  printf("Succcess\n");
}
else {
  printf("A too old version\n");
}
```

If you prefer to do the detection build-time, you can use a preprocessor #if expression like this:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#if LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM >= 0x072100
 /* this is 7.33.0 or later */
#else
 /* work-around for older libcurls */
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, or even just:

```
#ifdef CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER
  /* This version supports this option */
#else
  /* No, it doesn't */
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work since the CURLOPT_* names are part of an enum, not defined...