# how to check if a macro is available

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I was trying to see if my libcurl supports CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL, and got lost.  How can I find if a macro is set? What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(){
        printf("CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is %d\n", CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL);

#if (CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL == 1)
        puts("CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is 1");
#else
        puts("CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is NOT 1");
#endif

#ifndef CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL
        #define CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL 0
#endif
        printf("CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is %d\n", CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL);


#ifdef meh
        printf("meh is defined!\n");
#else
        printf("meh is NOT defined!\n");
#endif
        return 0;
}
```

Here's the output, it is wrong:

```
 $ ./a.out
CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is 1
CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is NOT 1 // <-- wrong
CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL is 0     // <-- nope..
meh is NOT defined!
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL` is not a macro. It is an `enum` value. If your problem is that you may be building with older versions of libcurl that did not have `CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL`, then what you need to do is not test whether `CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL` is defined but test what libcurl version is being used. Somebody more familiar with libcurl will have to answer that.

Comment: If you use an unknown identifier in an `#if` expression (i.e. something that's not defined as a macro), the preprocessor just assumes you meant `0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the pointers, sending me the [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233344/how-to-get-and-compare-libcurl-version) way.

My code has been modified thusly:

```
curl_version_info_data  *curl_version_data;
+#if LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM >= 0x073800
+        if (curl_version_data->version_num >= 0x073800){
+                printf("Setting CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL\n");
+                CURLsslset result;
+                result = curl_global_sslset((curl_sslbackend)1, NULL, NULL);
+                assert(result == CURLSSLSET_OK);
+        } else {
+                printf("libcurl version too old to set CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL\n");
+        }
+#else
+#warning "libcurl version too old to set CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL"
+               printf("libcurl version too old to set CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL\n");
+#endif
+
+
```

And it seems to be doing what my original intent was.